# as if she motored

Tags: meaning

There was a lady near the fence dressed in a long dark cloak that hid
everything except her high red-heeled shoes. Her face was half covered
by a black silk fringed mask, without goggles. And yet she did not look
in the least as if she motored.

This is from a Novel  by Kipling.
What does   the sentence below means?

And yet she did not look
in the least as if she motored.

I am glad if somebody would give me some advice.

Comment: Possibly [*motor*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/motor): "11. to ride in a motor vehicle; esp., to travel by automobile" or "12. (informal) to walk or otherwise proceed at a swift or steady pace"? I would guess "as if she traveled by auto at times", given the reference to goggles.

Answer (score 2):

I would define [motor](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/motor) as used here to mean either of:

> 11. to ride in a motor vehicle; esp., to travel by automobile
> 12. (informal) to walk or otherwise proceed at a swift or steady pace

As I read the passage, I would guess the meaning is like:

> And yet she did not look in the least as if she **traveled by auto**

given the reference to *goggles*.